# How to fix HashSet that allows duplicates?

Tags: java, set, hashset

I'm using a [java.util.Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface with a [java.util.HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) implementation and storing it in a Map.

I add an object to a Set then retrieve the Set object again and am able to add another object that is equal to the first.

When adding the seemingly equal objects, [Set.add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) returns `true` and two equal objects are stored in a HashSet. How is this possible and what can I do to fix this apparent breakage of the Set contract?

I'm using Java 12 via IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.6 and have checked my [java.lang.Object.hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) implementation for the class of the two objects I add to the Set, with both returning the same hash code.  I've also checked the [java.lang.Objects.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) implementation and it returns `true` when the method is used to check their equality. Both objects are wrapped in another object, Entity, but that only forwards the objects' `hashCode` and `equals` implementations.

```
class Model {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!(obj instanceof Offer)) {
            return false;
        }

        Offer offer = (Offer) obj;
        return Objects.equals(id, offer.id)
            && Objects.equals(name, offer.name)
            ;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 1;
        result = 31 * result + Objects.hashCode(id);
        result = 31 * result + Objects.hashCode(name);
        return result;
    }

    ...

}
```

```
class Store {

    ...

    private static class Entry {
        Object value;

        Entry(Object value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        Object getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return Objects.equals(value, obj);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return value.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Entry[value = " + value + "]";
        }
    }

    ...

    private Map<Class<?>, Set<Entry>> data;

    ...

    private Set<Entry> get(Class<?> type) {
        return data.getOrDefault(type, new HashSet<>());
    }

    @Override
    public void persist(Object obj) {
        Entry entry = new Entry(obj);
        Set<Entry> objects = get(obj.getClass());
        if (objects == null) {
            objects = new HashSet<>();
        }
        if (!objects.add(entry)) {
            throw new ObjectExistsException
                ("Object already exists: " + obj);
        }
        data.put(obj.getClass(), objects);
    }

    ...

}
```

When `obj1` and `obj2` of type Model are equal and `objects` already contains `obj1` wrapped in an Entry object, I expect `obj2` not to be added to `objects` when `obj2` is wrapped in `entry` and for `objects.add(entry)` to return `false` then an ObjectExistsException to be thrown.

However, what actually is happening is `objects.add(entry)` returns `true` and `obj2` wrapped in `entity` is being added to `objects`.

Comment: Use a `SortedSet` (also an `interface`), which implements `Set`, too, but does not allow duplicates and will have the items sorted... I would use a `TreeSet`.

Comment: `equals` should only ever compare to objects of its own type. Your `Model.equals` is comparing to `Offer`. Your `Entry.equals` is comparing `value`, not itself, to the pass-in object. Both are wrongly implemented.

Comment: Very true @Andreas; I just noticed this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return Objects.equals(value, obj);
    }
```

This isn't a correct implementation of `Entry.equals`. This potentially compares an `Entry` with the value held by the current entry. (Like comparing a letter with an envelope).

Make your equals method check that `obj` is an `Entry`, and get its value, and check equality to that.

Answer (score 0):

You were right @Andy Turner, but it was @Andreas that pointed me in the right direction.  I thought I would be lazy and not write a full `equals` method implementation, but it cost me.  It should have been like this:

```
private static class Entry {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!(obj instanceof Entry)) {
            return false;
        }

        Entry entry = (Entry) obj;
        return Objects.equals(getValue(), entry.getValue());
    }
    ...
}
```

Thank you both.

Comment: Some IDEs write `equals` methods for you. That's useful when you are lazy (as I am). Under IntelIj, use Alt + Insert shortcut and select `equals() and hashCode()`. :)